# Python urlopen return value

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib

I'm trying to pass existing URLs as parameter to load it's HTML in a single `txt` file:

```
for line in open('C:\Users\me\Desktop\URLS-HERE.txt'):
 if line.startswith('http') and line.endswith('html\n') :
    fichier = open("C:\Users\me\Desktop\other.txt", "a")
    allhtml = urllib.urlopen(line)
    fichier.write(allhtml)
    fichier.close()
```

but i get the following error:

```
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value returned by `urllib.urlopen()` is a file like object, once you have opened it, you should read it with the `read()` method, as showed in the following snippet:

```
for line in open('C:\Users\me\Desktop\URLS-HERE.txt'):
   if line.startswith('http') and line.endswith('html\n') :
      fichier = open("C:\Users\me\Desktop\other.txt", "a")
      allhtml = urllib.urlopen(line)
      fichier.write(allhtml.read())
      fichier.close()
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `urlopen` returns a reference to a file object from which you should retrieve HTML.

```
for line in open(r"C:\Users\me\Desktop\URLS-HERE.txt"):
 if line.startswith('http') and line.endswith('html\n') :
    fichier = open(r"C:\Users\me\Desktop\other.txt", "a")
    allhtml = urllib2.urlopen(line)
    fichier.write(allhtml.read())
    fichier.close()
```

Please note that `urllib.urlopen` function is marked as deprecated since python 2.6. It's recommended to use `urllib2.urlopen` instead.

Additionally, you have to be careful working with paths in your code. You should either escape each `\`

```
"C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\other.txt"
```

or use `r` prefix before a string. When an 'r' or 'R' prefix is present, a character following a backslash is included in the string without change.

```
r"C:\Users\me\Desktop\other.txt"
```